# if (a or b) and c statement

Tags: c#, if-statement

I'm having difficulty with a multiple option if statement.

Version 1 matches all without considering the && .contains("up")

```
if ( 
     || drow["ifName"].ToString().ToLower().Contains("vlan")
       || drow["ifName"].ToString().ToLower().Contains("st0")
       || drow["ifName"].ToString().ToLower().Contains("ge-0")
     && drow["ifStatus"].ToString().ToLower().Contains("up")
)
```

Version 2 matches none.

```
if ( (
       || drow["ifName"].ToString().ToLower().Contains("vlan")
       || drow["ifName"].ToString().ToLower().Contains("st0")
       || drow["ifName"].ToString().ToLower().Contains("ge-0")
     )
     && drow["ifStatus"].ToString().ToLower().Contains("up")
```

Something I am missing?

Table looks basically like

```
ifName   |   ifStatus
vlan.0   |   up
st0.1    |   up
pp0.0    |   up
ge-0/0/0 |   down
```

EDIT:

So the goal is to match only rows that have ifStatus = UP, also changed table to clarify a real example.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Version 2 looks to me like it should be right.

Comment: I would start by introducing variables to make the code easier to read...

Comment: You should extract a local variable or 2 to improve readability. Notice the common text `drow["ifName"].ToString().ToLower()`.

Comment: What is the question? Are you asking us how to use brackets?

Comment: And, fwiw, checking `.Contains()` for a single-character string seems problematic. For example, the `a` match makes the `vlan.10` match redundant.

Comment: So what are you expecting as a result and why? What are you trying to achieve is not clear from the posting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is your intended parse? logical OR (`||`) and logical AND (`&&`) are both left-associative and have different operator precedences:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx

Logical AND binds more tightly than does logical OR, so, an expression like

```
A || B || C && D
```

parses as if it were written

```
A || B || ( C && D )
```

If that is your intent, you're good. If not, you'll need to add parentheses as needed to get the desired parse. My suspicion is that your intended parse is more like:

```
(A || B || C ) && D
```

But that is not how your original test parses.

As a good general rule, if you're mixing ANDs and ORs in a logical expression, **always** use parentheses to indicate your intent. Misunderstanding operator precedence in logical expressions is a major source of bugs.

Answer (score 0):

This may not fix your problem, but it should make it easier to see what you're doing, as well as make the list more maintainable:

```
var matchNames = new[] {"a", "b", "c", "vlan.10"};
if (drow["ifStatus"].ToString().ToLower().Contains("up") //check up first, because it's cheaper
     && matchNames.Any(m => drow["ifName"].ToString().ToLower().Contains(m) )
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [linq](/questions/tagged/linq) to do this, for sample, add this namespace:

```
using System.Linq;
```

and try this:

```
string[] items = new[] { "vlan.10", "a", "b", "c" };

if (drop["IfStatus"].ToString().IndexIf("up", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1 &&
    items.Any(x => drop["IfName"].ToString().IndexOf(x, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1)
{
   // true...             
}
```

Read about the [`Turkey Test`](http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html), it shows why is important using the `IgnoreCase` method to compare instead `Contains`.

Answer (score 0):

Using a regex here can simplify the logic.

```
if((Regex.IsMatch(drow["ifName"].ToString().ToLower(), "[abc]"))
   && (Regex.IsMatch(drow["ifStatus"].ToString().ToLower(), "up")))
{
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**in first case:**  it produce `true` if any one of the expression (OR Expression or AND Expression)evaluates to `true`.
Note : it is similar to `if(A || B || C || D && E)`

so if any `OR` Expression`in (A,B,C)` evalutes to `true` or Expression `D and E` evaluates to `true` it becomes `true`.

**in second case :** it produce `true` if any one of the `OR` expressions is `true` and `AND` Expression `drow["ifStatus"].ToString().ToLower().Contains("up")` also must be `true` as you are using parenthesis pair.

Note : it is similar to `if( (A || B || C || D) && (E) )`

so if any one of the `OR` Expression`(A,B,C,D)` should evaluate to true and also AND expression `E` must be true to produce the result  `true`.

Try This:

```
String name=drow["ifName"].ToString().ToLower();
Sting status=drow["ifStatus"].ToString().ToLower(); 

if ( (name.Contains("vlan.10") || name.Contains("a") || name.Contains("b") 
       || name.Contains("c")) && (status.Contains("up")))
```

Comment: That's not correct: the first case evaluates to `true` if `drow["ifname"]` contains any of `"vlan.10"`, `"a"` or `"b"`, **OR** if `drow["ifname"]` contains "c" *and* `drow["ifstatus"]` contains `"up"`.

Comment: @NicholasCarey: Sorry it was my mistake , Edited my post please have a look.